# how to find required arguments quantity for python method

Tags: python

I want to find how many arguments required for any methods.
In a general way.

For example:

```
import queue

data_queue = queue.PriorityQueue()
```

Want to know how many arguments needed for 'data_queue'

Comment: *You* want to know that or do you want *your code* to automatically figure it out and something with that knowledge?

Comment: Read the docs? Call `help`? Call it with none and see who many it asks for in the TypeError? Or do you mean programmatically (in which case look into `inspect`)?

Comment: help(), docs! Thanks. Those are what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, call the `help` method. Just:

```py
import queue

data_queue = queue.PriorityQueue() 

help(data_queue)
```